# modify locals() like globals(), to insert variables into scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

(My python version is 3.7.0 on Ubuntu 19.10)

`locals()` and `globals()` produce dict-like objects that contain the references that are currently in scope. When a new key is added to `globals()`, it becomes available in global scope:

```
# the first two lines can be deleted
# they are just to make sure that I don't accidentally
# have a definition of a left in global scope

a = 1
del a
globals().update({'a':1})
print(a) # prints 1
```

This also works from inside a function definition. Please note, at the time when the function was defined, there was no global variable `a`. It is only created when the function is executed:

```
del a
def fun():
    globals().update({'a':1})
    print(a)

fun() # prints 1
```

This does not work with locals():

```
def fun():
    locals().update({'a':1})
    print(a)

fun() # NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Curiously, if I define a and then delete it, the error changes:

```
def fun():
    a = 1
    del a
    locals().update({'a':1})
    print(a) # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

fun()
```

And, although it is possible to update `globals()` and then to access the new reference inside a function, this is no longer possible, once a reference of the same name has at some point been in local scope:

```
def fun():
    a = 1
    assert 'a' in locals()
    del a
    assert 'a' not in locals()

    globals().update({'a':1})
    print(a) # UnboundLocalError

fun()
```

And another test, regarding the behaviour of `locals()` in global scope, out of a function:

```
a = 1
del a
locals().update({'a':1})
print(a) # prints 1
```

What are the semantics here? Why do the error messages change between NameError and UnboundLocalError? Is it possible to insert a reference into local scope?

Comment: `locals` provides a *representation* of the local scope, not necessarily an *interface* to it. But in the global scope, `locals()` behaves the same as `globals`, the global scope *being* the local scope.

Comment: One of the benefits of a local scope is that access to local values can be faster because the names in the scope can be determined at compile time. Being able to modify that set of names at runtime would break that benefit.